# How to understand the Ruzhiner's understanding on Noach's righteousness

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-noach, maseches-sanhedrin, noach-noah-the-man

So a family member sent me a very nice idea on Parshas Noach from the Ruzhiner Rebbe. The text reads as follows:

[image]

> Noach was a righteous man, he was perfect in his generation ([Bereishis 6:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.6.9?lang=bi&aliyot=0)) - there are those from our Rabbis that expound on this as a praise (for Noach) and there are those who expound on it as a disgrace (Refer to [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.6.9.2?lang=bi) there). By the expression of those who view it as a praise (for Noach) it writes "there are those from our Rabbis that expound", and then afterwards it writes that there are those who learn it out as a disgrace (for Noach) - but here it doesn't write our "Our Rabbis", since those who see it as a disgrace for Noach are not deemed as our Rabbis, because our Rabbis don't seek out to disgrace.

Whilst this is a very nice idea that points out the positives and sincerity of our Rabbonim, how then does he understand the Gemara in [Sanhedrin 108a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.108a.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) where Rabbi Yochanan takes the latter view.

It writes there:

> אלה תולדות נח [נח איש צדיק תמים היה בדורותיו] א"ר יוחנן בדורותיו ולא בדורות אחרים
>
> “These are the generations of Noah; [Noah was a righteous man, and wholehearted in his generations”] Rabbi Yocḥanan says: in his generation (he was righteous and perfect), but not relative to those of other generations.

Indeed, when looking into this Gemara, the [Ben Yehoyada](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.108a.17?lang=bi&p2=Ben_Yehoyada_on_Sanhedrin.108a.6&lang2=bi) writes that Rabbi Yochanan is building off his view that is aired in [Bereishis Rabbah 32:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.32.6?lang=bi):

> וַיָּבֹא נֹחַ וּבָנָיו וְאִשְׁתּוֹ וגו', אָמַר רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן נֹחַ מְחֻסָּר אֲמָנָה הָיָה, אִלּוּלֵי שֶׁהִגִּיעוּ הַמַּיִם עַד קַרְסֻלָּיו לֹא נִכְנַס לַתֵּבָה
>
> And Noach and his sons and his wife came etc - Rabbi Yochanan said that Noach was lacking in Emunah (faith); if the water (of the flood) hadn't
> arrived up to his ankles, he would never had entered into the Ark.

So Rabbi Yochanan clearly doesn't take such a positive view of Noach? How does this reconcile with the analysis of the Ruzhiner?

Comment: +1 Good question, and thanks for the source. The rabbi of the shul I davened on Shabbat said this same idea as a joke. Didn't know where he got it from. Shkoyech.

Comment: אין משיבין על ווארט חסידי

Comment: @JoelK - you said that not me :-)

Comment: Interestingly, Rashi ostensibly got his comment from a mixture of [Midrash Tanchuma](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Noach.5.4?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) Noach § 5 and [Tanchuma Yashan](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma_Buber%2C_Noach.6.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) Noach § 6. In the latter, it says: מהו בדורותיו, יש דורשין לשבח, ויש דורשין לגנאי

Comment: This can also be understood as Noach lacking a skilled trade and was thus constantly involved in trying to earn a living. He only stopped when he noticed the flood waters hitting his ankles. The first comment from the Ruzhiner is not disputing the accuracy that Noach was a Tzaddik in his generation (a limiting qualifier), only that those who follow the Ruzhiner’s derech don’t explain this as a negative trait for Noach. That the description that he was righteous is to be taken according to its plain meaning.

Comment: This screenshot was going around the chats last week. I don’t recall where, but someone suggested that he means in THIS SPECIFIC quote, that is lgenai, he’s not our rabboseinu and we adopt the other view.

Comment: Discussed [here](https://youtu.be/tm0Q9C5eGXA?t=327) by R. David Bar-Hayim.

Comment: @Alex - thank you! Great find!

Comment: @Alex - I just listened through. I don't subscribe to the Rov predicating his whole answer on the fact that the Rabbi who he heard it from comes  from the Da'ati Leumi community (as opposed to the Charedi approach). The fact that it is sourced from the Ruzhiner makes this claim flawed, aside from the political incorrectness of his claim.

Comment: If you look at Rashi's commentary as a whole, I don't think this idea can even get off the ground. Rashi uses language like this on various other occasions. E.g. Bereishis 9:2, Bereishis 22:1, Shemos 34:21, Shemos 35:3, etc. In all those instances is the second opinion not Rabboseinu?

Comment: @Dov I didn't listen to the whole thing. I just remembered from a few years ago that he spoke about this.

Comment: Also I stam don’t understand how the ribnitzer could make a statement like that at all about one of the Tannaim.. obviously he was huge himself and a massive tzadik but it seems interesting to say that about a drashas chazal